# Why is user asked for subscription to use Linux on AWS?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, centos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

From my thinking long until now, Linux is always free (except Red hat, that comes with support).

I'm trying to launch an instance on AWS EC2, but it is asking me to subscribe for a Linux AMI, which is around $0.01/hour.

Any reasons for Linux to be non-free on AWS?

Comment: AWS isn’t a free service.  Just because Linux isn’t free doesn’t mean AWS cannot charge for access to their hardware.

Comment: im not talking about hardware (charges are of course), im talking about the linux os software

Comment: Linux is free.  AWS = Amazon... "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)" Is Amazon giving away products or letting people use they're servers for free?

Comment: i can find the image CentOS7 by centos.org is being free, but no CentOS8 by centos.org yet. And those other CentOS8 images are not free

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You did not do the research. Answer is here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650697/cost-of-storing-ami

Comment: holy crab, this superuser.com should change name to superdownvote.com :)))) LOLLLLL

Comment: I agree. If you say something wrong they behave like ladies, when they are frustrated. I will minus you because you showed me that I did not try harder.